# Bash Script: Execute multiple command in single line && get the return code

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

I have a bash script file to process something.

control.sh :

```
c_command="echo 'Hello'; echo ', Stack Overflow';exit 9";
$c_command;
stat=$?;

if [ $stat -eq 0 ];then
      echo 'Do something....'
elif [ $stat -eq 9 ];then
      echo 'The system will be rebooting...';
else
      echo "..."
fi
```

I use the variable $c_command to execute the command, And I get the exit code is 0 not 9.
If I paste it in command line is work perfect, But when I run in script is very bad.

Generally, when I execute "exit" command in script, then the script will be exit.
And I just want the command done not the script and get the exit code from the command executed.

**I solved this problem:**

I put the code in $c_command to a script file and run it.

```
c_command="echo 'Hello'; echo ', Stack Overflow';exit 9";
echo "${c_command}" > tmp.sh;
/bin/bash tmp.sh;
stat=$?;

if [ $stat -eq 0 ];then
      echo 'Do something....'
elif [ $stat -eq 9 ];then
      echo 'The system will be rebooting...';
else
      echo "..."
fi
```

Comment: When I run this script, the commands in `$c_command` run fine and there is an exit status of 0. You find that the whole script terminates instead? Are you actually running the script that you pasted here?

Comment: Yep,

The $c_command should be return exit code is 9 not 0, cause I put the "exit 9" code in here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at what your script actually prints, and that should give you a clue about why the exit status is 0:

```
$ bash ./control.sh
'Hello'; echo ', Stack Overflow';exit 9
Do something....
```

After `c_command` is expanded, the semicolons are not treated as command separators, but as literal characters. As a result, you have a single `echo` command that exits 0, not a pair of `echo` commands followed by an `exit` command.

Instead of storing code in a string, you should use a function:

```
c_command () {
    echo 'Hello'; echo ', Stack Overflow';return 9 
}
c_command
stat=$?
```

Comment: First, Thank you very much..

But the $c_command is not fixed, I get it through "grep" and "cut".

Comment: @fozzmarc: Where do grep and cut come into it? Also, read [BashFAQ #50:I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: Ok, I read the doc, and I know it. I get it from "#update#3322#1.0#/bin/bash 3322.sh#touch a.file;echo 'success';exit 9" string.